# Angular js + bootstrap fixed layout

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want make fixed sidebar and nav like linked image

How can I do?

Comment: are you able to post what you have tried?

Comment: You can literally give those elements the `position: fixed` CSS attribute... Beyond that this question is a bit vague and broad.

Comment: Thanks reply! http://www.bootply.com/RWHOcbUof3 <=  I found the reference.